# How to check that all files from STDOUT are present on remote host? (via SSH)

Tags: shell

Let's imagine that I have list of files at host1

```
find /path/to -name "*.jpg" -print
```

I want to connect to host2 via SSH and check that all files from this list are present on remote host.

Please help, how can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use rsync in combination with ssh.

`rsync -avn -e ssh ./ username@remoteHost.net:~/files/`

This would do a dry run and list all files that are are on local machine, but not on the remote machine.  It would also list files that may have been changed on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Print files that don't exist on `host2`:

```
$ find /path/to -name "*.jpg" -print | ssh host2 "perl -lne'print unless -e'"
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested.

```
find /path/to -name "*.jpg" -print >base.txt
ssh user@host2 "find /path/to -name '*.jpg'" > check.txt
diff <(sort base.txt) <(sort check.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test first

```
file_list=`find /path/to -name "*.jpg" -print`
for local_file in `echo $file_list`; do
    ssh host2 "[ ! -f $local_file ] && echo \"file \$local_file not exist...\""
done
```

Comment: What's the point of forking `echo $file_list`? Simply use `for f in $file_list`. Any POSIX shell does word splitting.